# Resize Row Height on Font Size Change

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid-react

Increasing the row font size on the client side does not increase the row height dynamically even with the following are set, as per ag-grid documentation:

```
defaultColDef: { 
    wrapText: true,
    autoHeight: true
}
```

The cell content is truncated as the row height was not computed. So logically, the fix should have been to provide a means to set the new row height to a value greater than the new font size in pixels, then call to redraw the rows. However that did not seem to work, the row height is not being updated.

The state:

```
this.state {
    [..truncated for brevity..],
    defaultColDef: { 
        wrapText: true,
        autoHeight: true
      },
      rowData: createData(12),
      rowStyle: { fontSize: '20px' },
}
```

The functions:

```
  getRowHeight = () => {
    return rowHeight; //variable size declared above with value of 40
  };

  redrawAllRows = () => {
    size += 10; //variable size declared above with value of 20
    var rowFontSize = size + "px"; 
    this.setState({rowStyle: {fontSize: rowFontSize}}, () => {
        rowHeight = size + 5;
        this.gridApi.forEachNode(function (rowNode) {
          rowNode.setRowHeight(rowHeight);
        });
        this.gridApi.onRowHeightChanged();
        this.gridApi.redrawRows();
    });
  };
```

Render:

```
render() {
    return (
      <div style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%' }}>
        <div className="example-wrapper">
          <div style={{ marginBottom: '5px' }}>
            <button onClick={() => this.redrawAllRows()}>
              Redraw All Rows
            </button>
          </div>

          <div
            id="myGrid"
            style={{
              height: '100%',
              width: '100%',
            }}
            className="ag-theme-alpine-dark"
          >
            <AgGridReact
              modules={this.state.modules}
              columnDefs={this.state.columnDefs}
              defaultColDef={this.state.defaultColDef}
              rowData={this.state.rowData}
              getRowStyle={this.state.getRowStyle}
              onGridReady={this.onGridReady}
              rowStyle={this.state.rowStyle}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

The row height only increases when the text is wrapping. Am I missing something ?
Please follow [this link for a demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/TtFj423YZMlE3ems?preview)

Comment: Sorry but just to confirm, is the issue here that your `rowHeight` is not increasing when you increasing the font size in your `redrawAllRows` function? And your saying you have to set the text wrapping to `true` in order for the `rowHeight` to change?

Comment: When I change autoHeight to false, your rows grow bigger with the font (instead of currently going large then back to small again - but font size has new size), but eventually the text gets too large and the gets cut off at the top.

Comment: @VVS - I failed to mention that the data is coming from the backend, so there is a column with text of variable length that should not get truncated. Hence, the reason setting ```autoHeight: true```.